# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr table in latex

Tags: tables

I have the long table,

but there is a wrong message in overleaf !

Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

I didn't know how I resolve the problem?

this my code

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Comparison of the model for the Accuracy using different supervised machine learning algorithms with 3 types of Features selection: ANOVA, Chi-squared and No features selection.} 
\centering 
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc} %  
%\toprule
\hline 
& & & & \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Machine Learning Methods} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\centering Features Selection : Anova} &
\cmidrule{2-5} %\cmidrule{2-5}
%\parbox[c]{.45\linewidth}{\centering { ML Method }}}

 & {\centering Number of Features} & {Accuracy} & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy}  \\
 \hline 
%\midrule
& & & & \\
LR  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{5000 features}}  & 100\%  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{7000 features}}  & 100\% \\
% & & & & \\
SVM & & 100\% &             & 100\% \\
% & & & & \\
XGBoost & &  100\% & &  100\% \\
% & & & & \\
RF          & &100\%  & & 100\%  \\
% & & & & \\
Perceptron & & 100\% & & 100\% \\
& & & & \\
\hline %\hline

& & & & \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Machine Learning Methods} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\centering Features Selection : Chi-squared} &
\cmidrule{2-5} %\cmidrule{2-5}
%\parbox[c]{.45\linewidth}{\centering { ML Method }}}

 & {\centering Number of Features} & {Accuracy} & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy}  \\

 \hline 
%\midrule
& & & & \\
LR  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{5000 features}}  & 98.68\%  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{7000 features}}  & 98.68\% \\
%& & & & \\
SVM & & 100\% &             & 100\% \\
%& & & & \\
XGBoost & &  100\% & &  100\% \\
%& & & & \\
RF          & &100\%  & & 100\%  \\
%& & & & \\
Perceptron & & 100\% & &  100\%  \\
& & & & \\
\hline %\hline
& & & & \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Machine Learning Methods} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\centering No Features Selection} &
\cmidrule{2-5} %\cmidrule{2-5}
%\parbox[c]{.45\linewidth}{\centering { ML Method }}}

 &  & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy} &   \\

 \hline 
%\midrule
& & & & \\
LR  &  &\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ALL features}}  & 71.05\%  &  \\
%& & & & \\
SVM & & & 100\% &             \\
%& & & & \\
XGBoost & & & 100\% & \\
%& & & & \\
RF        &  & &100\%  &  \\
% & & & & \\
Perceptron & & & 100\% & \\
& & & & \\

\bottomrule


\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

I want to be like this
[image]

Comment: You can't write `& \cmidrule`. You need `\\\cmidrule`. Not an error but the weird mix of vertical rules, `\hline` and `booktabs`'s rules will make for a poor typographical result.

Comment: Er ... and the use of `adjustbox` probably constitutes a typographical sin ;).

Answer (score 1):

This answer has two parts.

### Part 1: Minimal Changes

Not very minimal, but the minimum I'd do. This fixes the errors and eliminates the scaling by turning the table. It also uses the `booktabs` approach. If you don't want to use `booktabs`, fine, but don't try to mix its approach with vertical rules and `\hline`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering 
  \caption{Comparison of the model for the Accuracy using different supervised machine learning algorithms with 3 types of Features selection: ANOVA, Chi-squared and No features selection.} 
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}  
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Machine Learning Methods} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Features Selection : Anova} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} 
    & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy} & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy}  \\
    \midrule
    LR  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{5000 features}}  & 100\%  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{7000 features}}  & 100\% \\
    SVM & & 100\% &             & 100\% \\
    XGBoost & &  100\% & &  100\% \\
    RF          & &100\%  & & 100\%  \\
    Perceptron & & 100\% & & 100\% \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Machine Learning Methods} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Features Selection : Chi-squared} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} 
    &  Number of Features & {Accuracy} & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    LR  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{5000 features}}  & 98.68\%  & \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{7000 features}}  & 98.68\% \\
    SVM & & 100\% &             & 100\% \\
    XGBoost & &  100\% & &  100\% \\
    RF          & &100\%  & & 100\%  \\
    Perceptron & & 100\% & &  100\%  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-5} 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Machine Learning Methods} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{No Features Selection} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} 
    &  & {Number of Features} & {Accuracy} &   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-5} 
    LR  &  &\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ALL features}}  & 71.05\%  &  \\
    SVM & & & 100\% &             \\
    XGBoost & & & 100\% & \\
    RF        &  & &100\%  &  \\
    Perceptron & & & 100\% & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

The result isn't great, but it is better:

[image: turned table]

### Part 2: Restructured Content

Answer (score 1):

The source of your error is that your Anova row (among others) is essentially the following:

```tex
col 1 & columns 2-5 & \cmidrule{2-5} col 6 & col 7 & col 8 & col 9 & col 10 \\
```

As cfr commented, you wanted `\\`  before `\cmidrule`, not `&`.  But as they also noted, don't mix booktabs with hlines and vertical rules (booktabs hates vertical rules, and defines its own horizontal rules that you should use instead).

If something applies to every row of a table, then I would recommend moving it from the table into the table's caption or a column header.  That greatly reduces the size of your table, making it much easier to compare the accuracy.  We can also `\usepackage{siunitx}` to gain its `S` column type.  I ended up with:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering 
  \caption{Percentage accuracy using different supervised machine learning methods with 3 types of features selection and differing numbers of features.} 
  \begin{tabular}{cSSSSS}\toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Feature selection and number of features} \\
    Method & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ANOVA} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Chi-squared} & {No Features} \\
    & {5000} & {7000} & {5000} & {7000} & {all features} \\\midrule
    LR  & 100 & 100 & 98.68 & 98.68 & 71.05 \\
    SVM & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 71.05 \\
    XGBoost & 78.95 & 77.63 & 82.89 & 82.89 & 68.42 \\
    RF & 88.16 & 84.21 & 88.16 & 88.16 & 71.05 \\
    Perceptron & 98.68 & 97.37 & 97.37 & 96.05 & 72.37 \\\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This has the output:
[image: code output]

(I am a bit confused about "No Features Selection" using "All features", so that column header is admittedly confusing.)

We've now made the table small enough that it doesn't need to rotate or have its size otherwise adjusted.  And the accuracies are collected together enough so that we can look at them all at once and make meaningful comparisons.